# Is an ApplicationBar supposed to respond to states in Blend?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, expression-blend

I'm trying out states in Blend, having defined a BusyStates group with the Busy and NotBusy states. Using the recording function I've changed the visibility of a PerformanceProgressBar and changed the IsEnabled state of the ApplicationBar menu and buttons.  When flicking between the states in Blend, the visibility of the progress bar changes, but not the enabled state of the ApplicationBar menu and buttons.

Is this a reflection of the fact that ApplicationBar is not a descended from FrameworkElement like the PerformaceProgressBar, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct, Visual States underneath are simply Storyboards that animate dependency properties, the ApplicationBar isn't a dependency object and can't be animated or bound to.

A rather annoying part of WP7 to be honest.